# Silex : The token storage contains no authentication token

Tags: silex

When trying to check whether the user is authenticated or not in layout

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    <p>Username: {{ app.user.username }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

I am getting an error as

```
Twig_Error_Runtime in Template.php line 304:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.") in "layout.html" at line 39.
```

This is the configuration of the security firewall. I need to only allow logged in users to access the website.

```
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'dev' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/',
            'security' => false
        ),
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login$',
        ),
        'secured' => array(
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout'),
            'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                // Specific class App\User\UserProvider is described below
                return new App\User\UserProvider($app['db']);
            }),
        ),
        'unsecured' => array(
            'anonymous' => true,
        )
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(
        // You can rename ROLE_USER as you wish
        array('^/.+$', 'ROLE_USER'),
        array('^/login$', 'SS'), // This url is available as anonymous user
    )
));
```

Any ideas to fix this is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the error message says that the error happens in `layout.html`, I'm guessing it is used on every page even the ones like /login that is not behind a firewall. The error is caused by calling `is_granted` when not behind a firewall.

So there are a few options:

1. Use a separate layout for login page that does not call `is_granted`
2. Check if there is an existing security token before calling  `is_granted`

Option 1 should be obvious so not going into more detail with that.

With option 2, you can do something like this to check for existing security token:

```
{% if app.security.token is not null and is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
```

Comment: I have tried the second one. But I was getting `Method "user" for object "Silex\Application" does not exist in "layout.html" at line 39`

Comment: Beau was pointing me to traits http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#traits . But I still don't know how to make use of it though.

Comment: Added an example of using SecurityTrait to the answer. Also, you could try `{% if app.user is defined and is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}`

Comment: I got the answer . It was `app.security.token` .

Comment: I have edited the answer. Will accept once it is corrected. Thank you.

Comment: When working on 2.0 I noticed usage of `{% if app.user is not null and is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}` and getting username via `{{ app.user.username }}` . Hope that helps someone.